# Typescript ESM jest - knex issue

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, knex.js

I have a TypeScript project which is being used as ESM.
When running tests with Jest I have ts-jest set up to utilise ESM transforming (config below)

When running any test it fails with the following message: "The requested module 'knex' does not provide an export named 'Knex'"

Within the file in question this is the syntax used to import the type definitions: `import { Knex } from 'knex';`

I understand that esm seems to struggle with named exports from CJS modules so have also tried: `import knex from 'knex'` then trying to reference `knex.Knex` which does not exist.

I have also tried the recommended solution in this article https://dev.to/asteinarson/typescript-node-js-importing-knex-into-es6-module-1poc which suggests the following syntax `import knex, { Knex } from 'knex'` but once again the named export is not found

```
{
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    clearMocks: true,
    collectCoverage: false,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    workerIdleMemoryLimit: '512MB',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['./src/**/*', '!./src/**/*.test.ts'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [],
    coverageProvider: 'v8',
    coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'clover', 'cobertura'],
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>jest.bootstrap.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/.build/', '/config/'],
    transform: {
      '.(ts|tsx)': ['ts-jest', { useESM: true }],
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '@/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
      '@tests/(.*)': '<rootDir>/tests/$1',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/`, '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$'],
    verbose: true,
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
};
```

This is mainly used for dependency injection through Inversify to inject a Knex connection, example:

```
class RepositoryClass {
 constructor(@inject(Types.DbConnectionOne) connection: Knex) {
    super(connection);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For others looking into this issue I think the error is somehow being caused by inversify as on removing the named imports on the inversify dependent files but leaving the ones which are as follows: `import type { Knex } from 'knex'` all works as expected. I will continue to investigate

Comment: I've dropped `jest` in favour of `vitest` because of better ESM support. Also `inversify` -> `iti` which I had to write myself

Comment: yeah saw that jasmine has full support so looking to make that change instead in the future seems like jest still has a way to go before supporting it fully: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/9430

Comment: I've migrated many repos and prob. thousands of tests. And it was really fast and easy, a few hours one day and a few other. Both a great anyway :)

Comment: As my understanding, knex only work in commonjs project. My setup is to use knex in another package, and keep the main package in esm